# AWS certificate manager Inaccessible host: `acm.undefined.amazonaws.com'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-certificate-manager

I have been using AWS SDK v2.846.0 for create a SSL certificate for diferent domains, but when I do a request the I get this error:

"Inaccessible host: `acm.undefined.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the` us-east-1' region."

Someone know what I could do?

I am using this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ACM.html#requestCertificate-property

Comment: How did you create your ACM service object? Did you pass an undefined region? Or does your AWS_REGION environment variable or credentials profile indicate a null/undefined region?

Comment: Hi Jarmod, I just imported the ACM from aws-sdk --> const AWS = require('aws-sdk');       Also create the objet --> const _ACM = new AWS.ACM();
And I set the us-east-2 region

Comment: How did you set the us-east-2 region? Can you share some code here?

Comment: `_ACM.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: secretKey,
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    region: 'us-east-2' 
})`

Comment: Pass those options into the ACM constructor, or do the config update *before* creating the ACM service object.

Comment: Thanks men, now it's works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the region is undefined in your ACM credentials object.

To supply options (including access key, secret key, and region), you can either pass them into the service constructor e.g.

```
options = { secretAccessKey: skid, accessKeyId: akid, region: 'us-east-2' };
acm = new AWS.ACM(options);
```

Or you can update the SDK's config object but you must do this *before* you create your service object, for example:

```
options = { secretAccessKey: skid, accessKeyId: akid, region: 'us-east-2' };
AWS.config.update(options);
acm = new AWS.ACM();
```